# What is the significance of the number of instances of a minifilter driver in the output of fltmc?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, filesystems

Pardon my ignorance as I only have a vague understanding of what minifilter drivers are.  We have Windows 10 user workstations with a minifilter driver installed called PtcVfsd.  When running `fltmc` from command line, some workstations report 2 instances of PtcVfsd, while others report 3 instances.

Output on Workstation 1:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>fltmc

Filter Name                     Num Instances    Altitude    Frame
------------------------------  -------------  ------------  -----
BHDrvx64                                5       365100         0
vfdrv                                   4       363500         0
vfpd                                    4       363400         0
eeCtrl                                  5       329010         0
SRTSP                                   6       329000         0
SymEFASI                                6       260610         0
storqosflt                              0       244000         0
wcifs                                   1       189900         0
CldFlt                                  0       180451         0
FileCrypt                               0       141100         0
PtcVfsd                                 2       137400         0
luafv                                   1       135000         0
npsvctrig                               1        46000         0
Wof                                     4        40700         0
FileInfo                                6        40500         0
```

Output on Workstation 2:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>fltmc

Filter Name                     Num Instances    Altitude    Frame
------------------------------  -------------  ------------  -----
BHDrvx64                                5       365100         0
vfdrv                                   5       363500         0
vfpd                                    5       363400         0
eeCtrl                                  5       329010         0
SRTSP                                   6       329000         0
SymEFASI                                6       260610         0
storqosflt                              0       244000         0
wcifs                                   1       189900         0
CldFlt                                  0       180451         0
FileCrypt                               0       141100         0
PtcVfsd                                 3       137400         0
luafv                                   1       135000         0
npsvctrig                               1        46000         0
Wof                                     4        40700         0
FileInfo                                6        40500         0
```

We are investigating an issue with the application related to this, and the workstations with 3 instances are experiencing the issue, while the others with 2 instances are not.  I noticed this difference between the sets of data we had so I'm trying to find out what it could mean.

I have posed this question to the software vendor, but I'm also asking here for a second opinion.

What is the significance of the number of instances of a minifilter driver in the output of `fltmc`?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The *number* isn't significant in itself, as far as I know.
But every instance can be attached to a different volume.
Issues may be coming from particular volume(s), which have instances attached on some of your machines, but not on others.

Try checking `fltmc instances`.